# Why do I need a setTimeout for animation to work?

Tags: javascript, css

In the code below, if I leave out the setTimeout, the transition doesn't work. What is the purpose of the setTimeout here?

```
  function showCircle (top, left, radius) {
  let circleDiv = document.querySelector(".circle"); 

  circleDiv.style.top = top + "px";
  circleDiv.style.left = left + "px";

  setTimeout (() => {
    circleDiv.style.width = radius*2 + "px";
  circleDiv.style.height = radius*2 + "px";
  },0)
}

showCircle (150,150,100);
```

Answer (score 2):

Without a delay (some browsers will require longer than a 0ms delay, which *basically* just makes the change wait until the stack is empty) the browser won't pick up that the css attributes changed.

Realistically, this has to do with browser "painting/repainting" for transitions.

Here is an article that addresses fixing this issue, in the same way you've "fixed" it.

http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2011/07/20/timing-issues-when-animating-with-css3-transitions/